# Community connector: setDateRangeRequired dynamic by other config options?

Tags: looker-studio

Built a google data studio 'community connector' for which only some of the data tables it can connect to require date range but others do not. For some reason the question of "date range required" is a per-connector config option. But I'd like to set the value differently depending on what other config options are set, such as the report selected.

Is there a way to setDateRangeRequired at schema time or later, for example, using a function which returns a different boolean depending on the request (getConfig doesn't get a request object -- too early)?

Seems like the kind of thing that should be set with setSchema instead, which can dynamically return different schemas depending on the config chosen by the user. PS - I know I can just ignore the date, but it seems like bad design to have a user select-able date that does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not currently possible.

Since `dateRangeRequired` is something that must be set for the `getConfig` response, there's no way to change it based on answers to the config.